# "HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized" on google chrome with Windows Authentication

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, security, authentication, iis-express

I have a new laptop. None of my previous applications are working and giving this error on Google chrome with Windows Authentication.

"HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized"

You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

Under project->properties-> Web, I have IIS Express set up as server. I am not using IIS 7 as web server.
Here are the steps to create a sample ASP.NET Web Application I am using. I am getting the same error in Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017.

Create new Project.
On next screen, select MVC and  Change Authentication
Select Windows Authentication and OK
In web.config it will show 
I set to Browse With - Google Chrome.

In Google Chrome it prompts to log in. When I enter my network credentials, it does not accept it and the login dialog keeps reappearing. when I hit cancel, I get error. In Internet explorer there is NO error.

[image: err image]

Comment: "0xc000006d" means "STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE", and IIS Express indicates that you gave wrong credentials. So it is likely that Google Chrome on your machine is not configured correctly.

Comment: Please guide what kind of configuration is required by Google Chrome? or if I need to reinstall it?

Comment: Chrome is not a developer tool, but a general web browser. So it is time to go beyond SO and use Google search.

Comment: In our team we are using Chrome developer tools as of now. I understand there are better tools now, but any thoughts on how to get this issue fixed?

Comment: Enterprise users can ping Google support service, https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6351685?hl=en while individual users should use Google's other channels for Chrome issues.